# BASE64 in HTML is not working

Tags: html, css, image, base64, data-uri

I had tried all possible way to display image using base64 string. But none of them are working. I tested it on IE6,7, Firefox 3. Please tell me what is wrong with below code.

```
<head>

<STYLE type="text/css">
div.image {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-image:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA...);
}
 </STYLE>
</head>
<body>
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,968" />
<img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." />
<script type="text/javascript"  src="data:text/javascript;base64,dmFyIHNjT2JqMSA9IG5ldyBzY3Jv..."></script>
<div class="image"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I've found [this page](http://www.sweeting.org/mark/blog/2005/07/12/base64-encoded-images-embedded-in-html) where it was (July, 2005) done for a GIF image. The example (still) works for me in Firefox 3.6. Just this interesting mention in the comments that maybe the URL is limited in size...

Comment: However the reason for this implementation, that the server was loaded by the accessses to the icons, should probably be mitgated by the advance on cache management (on server, network, client sides) since that time...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I tested it on IE6,7, Firefox 3

It just happens that none of these support data URIs (well, Firefox 3 does I think, just not very well). So you're doing nothing wrong.

If you need your background image to display in these browsers, just use traditional image files and `url()` instead.

Comment: +1, and here is a JS way to detect if your browser supports it. http://weston.ruter.net/2009/05/07/detecting-support-for-data-uris/

Comment: I tried on firfox 3.6, is there any other way to display image without giving any other external reference?

Comment: @articlestack: Firefox 3.6 should support data URIs correctly. But honestly, is it worth the hassle? Your image is probably not going to be very large, so one extra HTTP request for that image isn't going to hurt.

Comment: @BoltClock: even i dont use base64 normally. still i was searching another way of embeding images. So i met this requirement.

Comment: @articlestack: Data URIs are relatively new to browsers, so support is still not there yet until the old versions of IE are phased out.

Comment: @articlestack: depending on what you want to display, a JS library such as [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) might help.