# sending listview or gridview with image as Email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, listview, smtp

how can i send my ListView that contains images to a mail.  i can send the listview as an email, but the image does not show, please how can i use embedded images or resource linking inside a Listview. image comes on database to my listview.

Source Code.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="PlaceHolder1">
   <ItemTemplate>
    <table>
   <tr><td><asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#"Handler.ashx?ImID="+ Eval("route_Name") %>' Height="125px" Width="250px"/></td>
   <td><asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Description") %>'></asp:Label></td>
   </tr>
    </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

SMTP Code.

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
    HtmlTextWriter htmlTW = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    Panel1.RenderControl(htmlTW);
    string panelBody = sb.ToString();

    string fromEmail = lblempemailid.Text;
    string passwrd = lblemppaswrd.Text;
    string toMail = txtto.Text;
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

    message.To.Add(toMail);
    message.From = new MailAddress(fromEmail,"Company");
    message.Subject = txtmailsubject.Text;
    message.Body = panelBody;
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(fromEmail, passwrd);
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.Send(message);
    message = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

The image needs to be an absolute path, so instead of:

`/images/some_image.jpg`

it should be

`http://site_url/images/some_image.jpg`

Comment: yes this absolute path working when image path is on server but here image came from database. so there is no absolute path

Comment: In that case you can make a handler to serve up requests for your image, or you may be able to embed the image in the email directly by base 64 encoding it - but there may be issues - see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791601/base64-in-html-is-not-working?rq=1